# How to load the ng-template in separate file?

Tags: html, angular, ng-template, ng-container

In below sample, I have used `ng-template` like below and it is working fine.

> Sample link: [click here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mdksym-bihcup?file=default.html)

```html
<ng-template #template let-dataSource="">
  <span *ngIf="dataSource.iconCss" class="e-menu-icon {{dataSource.iconCss}}"></span> {{dataSource.header}} {{dataSource.text}}
  <span *ngIf="dataSource.templateHeader" class="e-login-content">
        <button ejs-button cssClass="e-info">Sign In</button>
      </span>
</ng-template>
```

But **I want to create a new file for `ng-template`** content and I want to use it in another file. I have tried like below but not working. Please help me find a solution for this case.

> template.html

```html
<ng-template #template let-dataSource="">
  <span *ngIf="dataSource.iconCss" class="e-menu-icon {{dataSource.iconCss}}"></span>
  {{dataSource.header}} {{dataSource.text}}
  <span *ngIf="dataSource.templateHeader" class="e-login-content">
    <button ejs-button cssClass="e-info">Sign In</button>
  </span>
</ng-template>
```

> default.html

```html
<div class="control-section">
  <ejs-menu #menu [items]='dataSource' [fields]='menuFields'>
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="template;"></ng-container>
  </ejs-menu>
</div>
```

> Sample 2: [sample 2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mdksym-r76qei?file=template.html)
>
> ref stackoverflow question: [angular2 ng-template in a separate file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49404822/angular2-ng-template-in-a-separate-file)

Comment: possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48555286/unable-to-use-ng-include-in-angular-5

Comment: Hi @JoelJoseph, it not like that.please read my question

Comment: you can create a separate  component  with your <ng-template> code and use the selector of the  same  component  so that you can use it in other places  as explained in the article in my comment

Comment: i have already tried not working sample link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mdksym-d5f7kx?file=template.component.ts

Comment: you will have pass data to the component or  create a service to communicate between parent and child component here. in the above stackblitz you are not passing data to the component

Comment: can you please update that sample and explain ..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

i got an answer for this question from github angular
please check this https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/27503

Answer:

> step1:

i have initialized my template as a new component as like below

**template.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-device',
  template: `
  <span *ngIf="dataSource.iconCss" class="e-menu-icon {{dataSource.iconCss}}"></span>
  {{dataSource.header}} {{dataSource.text}}
  <span *ngIf="dataSource.templateHeader" class="e-login-content">
    <button ejs-button cssClass="e-info">Sign In</button>
  </span>
`
})
export class DeviceComponent {
  @Input()
  dataSource: any;
}
```

**Then i have used that component template in my parent component as like below**

**default.html**

```html
<div class="control-section">
 <ejs-menu #menu [items]='dataSource' [fields]='menuFields'>
    <ng-template #template let-dataSource>
      <app-device [dataSource]="dataSource"></app-device>
    </ng-template>
  </ejs-menu>
</div>
```

> sample link  [sample click me](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mdksym-yf75gd?file=default.html)

Comment: Finally you were not able to use `ngTemplateOutlet` for that ?

Answer (score 2):

You can have a component for your templates (name it `tplComponent`) and inside that, create as many templates as you want. Then in other components, get an instance of `tplComponent` and get the template from that. Here is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49404822/angular2-ng-template-in-a-separate-file) that has an example of this approach (I haven't tried that though).

Please let me know if that works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use *ngTemplateOutlet to archive the same

Please refer the link below

[ngTemplateOutlet](https://alligator.io/angular/reusable-components-ngtemplateoutlet/)

Comment: I have tried not working. sample link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mdksym-5uqyyb?file=default.html

Comment: Hi, the link is not working anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're supposed templates like that. Simply create a classic component and if you need a template reference, wrap it in `ng-template`.