# Load template from a separate file in Angular 6.0+ calendar

Tags: html, angular, angular-calendar

I am currently using [angular calendar](https://angular-calendar.com/#/customise-current-time-marker) in my project & customized it quite a bit. The customization is done by using `<ng-template>` and I currently have them all in the same file which got out of hand.

Here's a simplified version:

`app.component.html`

```
<!-- Load this from a separate file -->
<ng-template
  #currentTimeMarkerTemplate
  let-columnDate="columnDate"
  let-dayStartHour="dayStartHour"
  let-dayStartMinute="dayStartMinute"
  let-dayEndHour="dayEndHour"
  let-dayEndMinute="dayEndMinute"
  let-isVisible="isVisible"
  let-topPx="topPx"
>
  <div
    class="cal-current-time-marker"
    *ngIf="isVisible && showMarker"
    [style.top.px]="topPx"
  ></div>
</ng-template>
<!-- Load this from a separate file -->

<!-- Use the reference of the above template -->
<mwl-calendar-week-view
  [currentTimeMarkerTemplate]="currentTimeMarkerTemplate"
  [viewDate]="viewDate"
  [dayStartHour]="dayStartHour"
  [dayEndHour]="dayEndHour"
>
</mwl-calendar-week-view>
```

I tried creating `app-my-template.component.html` & moved the `<ng-template>` tag inside of it, then edited `app.component.html` as follows:

```
<app-my-template #external_template></app-my-template>
<mwl-calendar-week-view
  [currentTimeMarkerTemplate]="external_template"
  [viewDate]="viewDate"
  [dayStartHour]="dayStartHour"
  [dayEndHour]="dayEndHour"
>
</mwl-calendar-week-view>
```

But I get the following error:

> "Type 'MyTemplate' is missing the following properties from type 'TemplateRef': elementRef, createEmbeddedView"

I also tried [this stackoverflow response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53663118/10543130), however the `<ng-template>` part is kept outside of the component, which doesn't work in my case since I have a bunch of variables associated with `ng-template` itself.

As for my question, how do I load the entirety of `ng-template` including the tag itself from another file? Thank you.

Comment: try accessing the `ng-template` inside the `app-my-template` component, maybe like `[currentTimeMarkerTemplate]="external_template.currentTimeMarkerTemplate"`

Comment: Using this gives Property `currentTimeMarkerTemplate` does not exist on type `MyTemplate`. I tried adding `@ViewChild('#currentTimeMarkerTemplate') currentTimeMarkerTemplate!: TemplateRef<any>;` inside of `MyTemplate` however it ignores my template & uses the default one.