# Injecting component to ng-container? (load ng-template from file)

Tags: javascript, angular, ng-template, ng-container

I'm trying to build a simple tabs-menu in my **Angular** app.

**parant.component.html:**

```
<div>
  <button (click)="selectTab(1)">Tab1</button>
  <button (click)="selectTab(2)">Tab2</button>

  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="(selected == 1) ? template1 : template2">
  </ng-container>

  <ng-template #template1>I'm page 1</ng-template>
  <ng-template #template2>I'm page 2</ng-template>
</div>
```

**parant.component.ts:**

```
public selected = 1;
public selectTab(tabName) {
  this.selected = tabName;
}
```

This is working fine, as long as the `<ng-template>` is part on the same page html. Now my pages (the content of *#template1* and *#template2*) become complex and I want to move them to separate components.

How could I inject component into `<ng-container>`??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To inject a Component into `<ng-container>`, you didn't need to use `*ngTemplateOutlet`, instead use `*ngComponentOutlet`.

You can see the full API at: [NgComponentOutlet](https://angular.io/api/common/NgComponentOutlet)

**tab1.component.html:**

```
<p>tab1 works!</p>
```

**tab2.component.html:**

```
<p>tab2 works!</p>
```

**parent.component.html:**

```
<div>
  <button (click)="selectTab(1)">Tab1</button>
  <button (click)="selectTab(2)">Tab2</button>

  <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="activeTab">
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

**parant.component.ts:**

```
import { Tab1Component } from './tab1.component';
import { Tab2Component } from './tab2.component';
...

public activeTab = Tab1Component;

public selectTab(tabName) {
  if (tabName == 1) {
    this.activeTab = Tab1Component ;
  }
  else if (tabName == 2) {
    this.activeTab = Tab2Component ;
  }  
}
```

And don't forget to add these dynamic components to the `entryComponents` section.

**app.module.ts:**

```
import { Tab1Component } from './tab1.component';
import { Tab2Component } from './tab2.component';
...
@NgModule({
  ...
  entryComponents: [
    Tab1Component,
    Tab2Component,
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

> compnent-templet1 and compnent-templet2 is name of component  which
>   previously was in ng-templet now you put them in component*

```
 <ul>
            <li *ngFor='let link of links'>
                <ng-container 
                     [ngTemplateOutlet]="link.type == 'complex' ?complexLink : simpleLink" 
                     [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{link:link}">
                </ng-container>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <ng-template #simpleLink let-link='link'>
            Simple : {{ link.name }}
    <compnent-templet2 [input]="link.somevalue"></compnent-templet2>
        </ng-template>

        <ng-template #complexLink let-link='link'>
            Complex : {{ link.name }}
    <compnent-templet1 [input]="link.somevalue"></compnent-templet1>
```

Comment: But if I have 15 tabs, I need to add them all the the same html? can't I separate them in separate files?

Comment: you can create one component which will be responsible to inject  right component , you can pass some in put value to the component then that componet will decide which component actually need to part of ng-templat